# Custom Relative Layout with ads

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, android-relativelayout

i am trying to make an layout like this but if a add padding from tom my ad view become small what am i doing wrong can someone please help me am not good with layouts should i use relative layout or make it via Linear layout i want to work it on all kind of screen sizes please guide me how can i make exact layout like this one 
 [image: this is layout i want to make]

and this is my code

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="40sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:text="the End"/>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_close"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="start" />



        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_play"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="close" />

    </LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center|bottom"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.NativeExpressAdView
        android:id="@+id/nativeAd"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        ads:adSize="280x250"
        ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-394859312"/>

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/bannerAd"
        xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_id">
    </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
</LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the padding to your parent linearLayout

```
android:padding="16dp"
```